# Closing fd returned from _open_osfhandle without closing underlying handle

Tags: c, windows, libpq

I have a program using libpq on windows, and I use `_open_osfhandle(PQsocket(cnxn), 0)` so that I can call `select()` on it.

My problem is, libpq is closing the underlying socket in `PQfinish()` so I get assert failures when calling `_close()` on the value returned by `_open_osfhandle()`

Is there a way to close a CRT file descriptor, without also closing the underlying handle?

**EDIT**

The reason I need this, is because after about 512 connections, `_open_osfhandle()` fails saying too many open files. Also, I tried `_free_osfhnd` (I found it in close.cpp when visual studio showed me the source of the assert) and it still failed.

Comment: Use `DuplicateHandle` to duplicate the handle returned by `PQsocket`, and pass the duplicate to `_open_osfhandle`.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Thank you. I have the code running, but it will take some time before we know for sure if it worked or not. I will let you know in a few minutes.

Comment: @RaymondChen, It works, thank you so much. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Go ahead and post the answer yourself, with whatever level of detail you feel appropriate, and then accept it. You have my permission. (I don't need imaginary internet points.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Raymond Chen's comment told me to try DuplicateHandle, and this worked.

Here is where I dupe it:

```
HANDLE h_dup_handle = 0;
SERROR_CHECK(DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), PQsocket(A->cnxn),
             GetCurrentProcess(), &h_dup_handle, 0, TRUE,
             DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS), "DuplicateHandle failed!");
A->int_windows_pq_handle = _open_osfhandle(h_dup_handle, 0);
SERROR_CHECK(client->int_windows_pq_handle != -1, "_open_osfhandle failed!")
```

(SERROR_CHECK is a macro that goes to the `error` label if the condition is not met)

Here is where I close it:

```
PQfinish(client->cnxn);
_close(client->int_windows_pq_handle);
```